# Firebase Authentication Security

Tags: android, firebase, security, firebase-authentication

I could not find this anywhere, but..

How does Firebase provide security on the persistence of user sessions in Android? So, a user logs in, and he can now perform certain actions corresponding to his privilege, obviously the auth token and other data is hold somewhere for the android app to send to firebase. Where? How is security enforced?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android provides the security, and Firebase doesn't really have to do anything special.  On Android, each app is provided a dedicated per-app local storage space that only the app process itself can read and write.  No other apps can access this.  This is where the token is stored.  According to the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage):

> **App-specific storage**: Store files that are meant for your app's use only, either in dedicated directories within an internal storage volume or different dedicated directories within external storage. *Use the directories within internal storage to save sensitive information that other apps shouldn't access.*

Any app can use its own dedicated space to store data securely.  This is what the Firebase SDKs use.

Answer (score 0):

What I can say from my experience with firebase auth store current login user `info`
in `share preference` i.e. `APP_SHARED_PREFERENCES` inside that here is column  for firebase auth `com.google.firebase.auth.api.Store.{some random string}` inside that you can find key value pairs as follows
Key `com.google.firebase.auth.FIREBASE_USER` value > `current login user info`
key `com.google.firebase.auth.GET_TOKEN_RESPONSE` value > `token value for user`

you can find this using this [library](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database)
for debugging database in debug mode

[image]